# Paginate entries ordered by a custom date field

Tags: craft3, pagination, query

I'm trying to paginate a bunch of events based on their start date. The order part is working correctly, but each consecutive page just loads the exact same entries. My code:

```
{% set events = craft.entries().section('events').limit(2).order('startDate asc') %}
{% paginate events as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

{% for event in events %}
    // Event content
{% endfor %}

{% if pageInfo.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
{% if pageInfo.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Pulling it all inside paginate fixed it:

```
{% paginate craft.entries().section('events').limit(2).order('startDate asc') as events %}

{% for event in events %}
    // Event content
{% endfor %}

{% if paginate.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
{% if paginate.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
```